# Router sending DHCP NAK to PC, but only when switching operating systems

Tags: networking, router, multi-boot, dhcp, mac-address

Here's the situation:

I have a PC with a single ethernet interface, with a single MAC address.

On my router (a Linksys E4200 with stock software), I have a DHCP reservation set to the MAC address of this interface, instructing it to always give a particular IP.

Normally, this works fine. 
However, this computer is running both Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) and Windows 10.
After booting into Windows, everything works as expected and I have the correct IP. 
However, upon booting *back* into Linux, the network "spins" forever and fails to connect. Running `journalctl -xe` shows many copies of:

```
Apr 17 23:38:41 <snip> dhclient[2030]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20 (xid=0x40fd6476)
```

And in particular, this exchange:

```
Apr 17 23:40:29 chase-lx dhclient[3456]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.105 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x242aef01)
Apr 17 23:40:29 chase-lx dhclient[3456]: DHCPNAK from 192.168.1.1 (xid=0x1ef2a24)
```

Sure enough, to confirm, viewing logs on the router admin interface yields:

```
Wed, 17 Apr 2019 23:40:28 sending NAK to <the mac address>
```

So, the router is *explicitly* denying the DHCP request and effectively refusing to honor the DHCP reservation.

Why would the router be doing this - how can it even distinguish that a "different machine" is making the DHCP request if it comes from the same interface.
More importantly, is there a way I can configure my router to *not* do this?

Right now, one way to fix it is to use another computer to go to the admin interface, and delete from the DHCP client table the entry corresponding to the IP/MAC address.
After deletion, the machine in limbo succeeds in connecting.

Comment: Does this DHCPNAK actually show up on the client (either in dhclient logs, or through tcpdump/Wireshark)? Is this _really_ sent in response to DHCPDISCOVER, as opposed to a "resuming" DHCPREQUEST?

Comment: Yes, grepping through journalctl does show an instance of `DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.105 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x242aef01)` followed by `DHCPNAK from 192.168.1.1 (xid=0x1ef2a24)`. You're right, I edited the question to reflect the explicit request -> denial